# Avoiding power drop in LED strip lights

Tags: led, series, basic

I am wiring a van and will be putting in ~25-30 feet of LED (RGB+W) strip lighting. My main power supply is a 300 Ah, 12 V battery. I am familiar with LED strips, dividing and connecting them, but I am unfamiliar with voltage drop across multiple LED strips.

It would be easiest to just have one power source for the entire lot of my LED strips, daisy chain them together in series for a total of 25-30 feet. That way I can have them all on the same circuit, thus same switch. The lights are 5.5 W, over 25 feet thats about 143 W. 143 W/12 V = ~12 A.

First off, does this sound right? 12 A sounds like a lot. Would doing 13 ft + 13 ft in parallel off the single power source cause significant power drop?

I'm new to circuitry. If I did it in parallel what would my amperage be?
I feel like in series 25 feet is not that much and I wouldn't experience much voltage drop in the later LED strips. Most posts I've read talk about power drop after ~50 feet.

Comment: It depends on the strip lighting.  The size of the conductors on the strip will determine the resistance per foot which in turn determines the amount of voltage drop and maximum current capability.  The datasheet for your specific strip should tell you the maximum length.  143W of LED lighting will turn the inside of your van into a small star; it's roughly equivalent to 1430W of incandescent lighting.

Comment: Lol, I guess the data sheet I grabbed for my calculation was a bit off. I think if I chain two 16ft light strips together there shouldn't be too much power drop. I'll have the later strips for under counter, where strength is not as essential. THANKS!

Comment: If you put two strips in series by the end of the 2nd strip the LEDs will be noticeably dimmer which with multi-color LEDs will look like a color shift. The way I solved it and seen others do is wire a 2nd pair of pwr/gnd wires (22 gauge or so) from the power supply alongside both strips and connect it at the far end of the 2nd strip. This greatly reduces the impedance difference different LEDs have from the power source.

Comment: what is preventing you from running tests before you start the installation?

Comment: You used 5.5W *per foot* in your calculations, right? Seems like quite a lot of light. Are you sure it's not 5.5W in total?